# Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I created a custom module. The call which is failing is:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[modulename]/[model]')->getCollection(); 
$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_public', 1)->getSelect();
$collection = Mage::getModel('[modulename]/[model]')->getCollection()->getFirstItem();//
```

Obviously, I screwed something up in my models. Here they are:

Model/[Model].php

```
class [namespace]_[modulename]_Model_[model] extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
     public function _construct() {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('[modulename]/[model]');
     }   
}
```

Model/Mysql4/[Model].php

```
class [namespace]_[modulename]_Model_Mysql4_[model] extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract        {
    public function _construct() {
       $this->_init('[modulename]/[model]', 'id');
     }   
 }
```

Model/Mysql4/[Model]/Collection.php

```
class [namespace]_[modulename]_Mysql4_[model]_Collection extends
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract {
       protected function _construct() {
          //parent::_construct();
          $this->_init('[modulename]/[model]');
       }   
}
```

The collection works, sort of.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('[modulename]/[model]')->getCollection()->getData();
```

The code above returns all rows in the table. It fails as soon as I try to apply another function to it. From what I've read addFieldToFilter should just work for a properly set up collection.

This is in magento. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error says that the variable on which you are calling getFirstItem() is not an object. It should be an object, then only you can call functions on it. You have mentioned your models and everything else pristinely but i cant find the line where you are calling getFirstItem(). It would help community to answer your question if you mention that piece of code too.

Comment: Good point. Line added. The root of the problem is that the collection is null and I don't immediately see why that is the case.

Comment: The issue is with one of the model names. It should be [namespace]_[modulename]_**Model**_Mysql4_[model]_Collection extends
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract

Comment: Have you defined the resource model your `config.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. What is the class of your Object in question and check if this class has getFirstItem() function in place.

Note:
abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract extends Varien_Data_Collection_Db  does not have getFirstItem()

class Varien_Data_Collection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable

has this function.

So check as stated above what is the class of your Object class in question.

Paste your specific code lines where this error is coming from.